# How can I figure out section headings in a document?

Tags: nlp, text-mining

I have a large number of different XML documents with associated style sheets (SEC financial filings). Are there any natural language processing (or other) tools that I can use to try to automatically extract section headings?

Comment: Are the section headings tags in the xml, or are you trying to derive them via natural language processing methods?

Comment: There will inevitably be some kind of tags associated with the headings, but its not standard between documents. Here's one example (which happens to be html) https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320340/000143774915020747/ins20150930_10q.htm

Comment: NLP is not a tool to extract headings.   Extract the text and use tags as features.  And html is not the same as xml - it will be different tools for extraction.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are lucky and the section headings are XML-tagged. So you can use XSLT transformations or Python lxml.etree to get rid of them or to extract them.